# How to do Array manipulation (from 4 by 2 to 2 by 2)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following:

```
for (i, (startX, startY, endX, endY)) in enumerate(rects):
    cX = int((startX + endX) / 2.0)
    cY = int((startY + endY) / 2.0)
    inputValues[i] = (cX, cY , startX,endx)

D = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(np.array(someOtherList), inputValues)
```

This `mcdist` method finds the distance between the pairs of the 2 lists.
The `inputValues` is an array where each item is `x, y, startX, starty`.

How can I pass input values to the method without the start/end so they don't get into the equation?

Basically I want to pass `inputValues` to the `cdist` method as if it was:

```
inputValues[i] = (cX, cy)
```

I don't want to create 2 lists, so I was hoping there is a pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Why are you `opposed to inputValues[i] = (cX, cy)`?

Comment: There is no way to pass an object "as if" it were another object, you will have to create a list without the extra tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that `rects` is a list of 4-tuples or 4-element lists. You can do

```
rects = np.array(rects)
```

To turn it into an array, which will make it much easier to manipulate. Now you can get the centers, the ends and whatever else you want. For example:

```
cx = rects[:, ::2].mean(axis=1)
cy = rects[:, 1::2].mean(axis=1)
input_values = np.stack((cx, cy, rects[:, ::2]), axis=1)
```

You can get a subset with

```
D = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(np.array(someOtherList), inputValues[:, :2])
```

This will create a cheap view of the original data, without copying the elements you care about. Keep in mind that `cdist` will turn anything you pass in into an array anyway.

Comment: Awesome, the last piece of code and the idy of numpy is amazing

Comment: @Snake.Glad you liked it. Enjoy.